# Detailed logging running continually

Tags: logging

On some but not all records, we see over 2K change log entries.

[image]

On this record, the change log started and ran continuously from 11-26-19 to 1-20-2020

[image]

Another instance I had imported to the preferred communication field and the import ran for ~20 minutes. The change log was continually getting written to for the entire import process.

For now, I have turned off detailed logging. We are using a separate db for it. Thoughts on what is going on here?

Comment: Do you have cron scripts that do something related every 15 min? Something that maybe only touches some contacts?

Comment: The civicrm_log doesn't show these numerous changes.

Comment: It could be something like SQL statements or calls that use something like `$dao->save();` instead of the api, so it might bypass civicrm_log but not the triggers. The report you've screenshot'd will show what the changes are if you click on them - do they give any clues?

Comment: I've seen something similar which was the summary fields extension running every hour and so almost every contact had an update logged every hour.  So, I changed the frequency to daily.

Comment: I do have the summary fields job running hourly. I have switched to daily.

Comment: Let me know if the logs reduce and I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PR resolved this https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/pull/62

with an **Exclude Summary Fields from logging?** feature.

> When advanced logging is turned on, you can exclude Summary Fields
> from being logged to increase performance and reduce clutter.